# Android webview keyboard scrolling issue

Tags: android, android-webview, android-keypad, android-virtual-keyboard

I am using android webview in my application, I have a small toolbar on top of my keyboard, so every focus on a field, I am trying to scroll webview using onfocus event listener (so that field wont get covered), but this is working on when user selects the field, but not with tab key press.